# how to open running instance of a class

Tags: java, chat, instance

Hi I am creating a chat application, I have a contacts list in a JList which is connected to mysql database. here is my code for the contacts list;

```
if (evt.getClickCount() == 2) {
    String userID = lbluserID.getText();
    String selectedContact = jList1.getSelectedValue().toString();
    ChatClient chatClientObject = new ChatClient(selectedContact, userID);  
    ChatClient.runchatClient(selectedContact, userID);
}
```

The problem I am having is when I click on a contact it will open the chat client for that contact, however if I click again on the contact from the contacts list a new chat client will open. how can I fix this so the same instance of the chat client is used for each user.

Comment: You will need to keep a cache of chat clients as well as the code to reuse them.

Comment: Add code for ChatClient. is "runchatClient" a static method in ChatClient class?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to either monitor your open windows (as mentioned in the comments by @Code-Guru) or be able to check during runtime if the window is open. Try something like

```
if (evt.getClickCount() == 2) {
    String userID = lbluserID.getText();
    String selectedContact = jList1.getSelectedValue().toString();
    ChatClient chatClientObject = new ChatClient(selectedContact, userID);  
    if (!chatClientObject.isOpen())
        ChatClient.runchatClient(selectedContact, userID);
}
```

Or the static approach

```
if (evt.getClickCount() == 2) {
    String userID = lbluserID.getText();
    String selectedContact = jList1.getSelectedValue().toString();
    ChatClient chatClientObject = new ChatClient(selectedContact, userID);  
    if (ChatClient.isChatClientOpen(chatClientObject))
        ChatClient.runchatClient(selectedContact, userID);
}
```

You might want to be able to do the check before creating the new instance, probably based only on your 2 strings. As for the implementation, it's hard to say without knowing how your program is structured. You can either keep some list of open windows or attempt to fetch a window at runtime and interpret the result.

---

With the risk that comes with not knowing your bigger picture, I would suggest to make the `runchatClient` method non-static. Used in this way:

```
ChatClient chatClientObject = new ChatClient(selectedContact, userID);
chatClientObject.run();
```

Or at the least don't make the static call `ChatClient.runchatClient` have the arguments fed to it all over again, instead use

```
ChatClient.runchatClient(ChatClient chatClientObject);
```